# Logical Indexing Cell Array

Tags: matlab, logic, cell-array

I have a cell array with two types of strings: 'ANN' and 'QTR'.

I am trying to get a vector with ones if cell array equals 'QTR'.

Here's an example of what I am trying to do:

```
A = {'ANN';'ANN';'ANN';'ANN'; 'QTR'; 'ANN'; 'QTR'; 'QTR'; 'QTR'; 'QTR'};
logic1 = A == 'QTR'
```

However, this sort of notation doesn't seem to work well with cells. 
I have looked for workarounds, but did not manage to find any.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the `strcmp` function:

```
strcmp(A,'QTR')
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the way to go. I will accept the answer in 15min (apparently I need to wait to do so).